# overriding onNavigationItemSelected stops navigation to fragments on item click in drawerLayout

Tags: android, listener, android-architecture-navigation, navigationview, android-navigationview

overriding onNavigationItemSelected stops navigation component functionality of opening fragments on item click, instead it calls onNavigationItemSelected and nothing else happens.

navigation view setup called in on create

```
    private fun setupNavigationDrawer(){

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navigationView,navHostFragment.findNavController())
        binding.navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)


    }
```

activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

onNavigationItemSelected

```
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(binding.mainActivityRootView.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)){
            binding.mainActivityRootView.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
        }
        else if(binding.mainActivityRootView.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            binding.mainActivityRootView.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        }
        return true

    }
```

Navigation view xml

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_home_navigation_drawer"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingEnd="15dp"

        app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_navigation_drawer_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/lipstick"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:drawerLayoutCornerSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_main_blue"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:tint="@color/lipstick" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView41"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserratmedium"
                android:text="Version IMPLEMENT"
                android:textColor="@color/pinkish_grey"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

i have set menu item id as navigation fragment id and it works without the onNavigationItemSelected being set i also have navigation view below fragment container in xml

i tried to

-change return value onNavigationItemSelected
-setting up onNavigationItemSelected listener before setupWithNavController which results in the listener not getting called at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i solved it by manually opening fragments

from

```
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if(binding.mainActivityRootView.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)){
        binding.mainActivityRootView.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
    }
    else if(binding.mainActivityRootView.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        binding.mainActivityRootView.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    }
    return true

}
```

to

```
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if(binding.mainActivityRootView.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)){
        binding.mainActivityRootView.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
    }
    else if(binding.mainActivityRootView.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        binding.mainActivityRootView.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    }

    when(item.itemId){
        else ->{
            NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item,navHostFragment.findNavController())
        }
    }

    return true
}
```